# Find out the average value of inputted integers

Tags: c++

I managed to get this program to work. If the user types an unfixed amount of integers, the program will calculate the average value of it. But I need to end it with `<Ctrl-D>` in my terminal (end of file) in order for it to work. Why can I not just press enter for it to work?

I also believe that I've used an unnecessary amount of variables. Can it be narrowed down to maybe 2 variables?

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

  using namespace std;


int main ()

{

  int digit {};
  int res {};
  int counter {};


  cout << "Type in integers: ";

  while (cin >> digit)
    {
      counter ++;
      res += digit;
    }

  cout << "The mean was " << setw(1) << setprecision(1) << fixed << static_cast<double>(res) / static_cast<double>(counter) << endl;

return 0;

}
```

Comment: `cin >> digit` will only test false if an error occurs reading the value of `digit` from `std::cin`.   Entering whitespace (like pressing enter) does not put `std::cin` into an error state.  Instead, the read via `cin>>digit` skips whitespace and continues reading until there is other input (that either can be interpreted as an integral value, or puts the stream into an error state).   If you want to exit the loop when the user hits enter, you need to use some other mechanism of reading that actually takes account if a newline is in the stream.

Comment: I got taught to do that instead of using "= 0"

Comment: If you want to read one string of data ending with a newline and then extract all the integers and average them then use getline to read the line and fill a stringstream with the result and extract from that instead.   https://onlinegdb.com/kpTvnr3ZL

Answer (score 1):

> Why can I not just press enter for it to work?

Because that's not how the overloaded `>>` formatted extraction operator works. This operator skips over an unlimited amount of whitespace characters, including newline characters, until it reads the integer. It's simply how it works: it will read newlines and spaces, after newlines, and spaces, until it sees a digit. That's its mission in life: read and skip over spaces and newlines until it reads at least one digit. It never gets tired of reading newlines and spaces, and will keep going as long that's the case.

To handle input in the fashion you describe requires a completely different approach: using `std::getline` to read a single line of input into a `std::string`, up until the next newline character. Then, once that's done, you can check if the `std::string` is empty, which means that no input was entered, and then terminate; otherwise take the input in `std::string` and convert it to an `int` value (using `std::stoi`, `std::from_chars`, or a `std::istringstream` -- take your pick), and then proceed with the existing algorithm.

> Can it be narrowed down to maybe 2 variables?

How do you expect to do that? Hard, immutable logic dictates that you must keep track of at least two discrete values: the total sum and the number of values read. But then you just ran out of variables. You have no more variables to use for storing the next read value (if there is one), using whatever approach you chose to use. So, you can't do it. Rules of logic require the use of at least three variables, possibly more depending on how fancy and robust you want your input validation to work.